# Laravel Model Extending

Tags: php, laravel

I have a question about models structure.

I created a model called User.php

Than I would like after get a record from DB initialize another class which extends User class based on the value from DB. I.e. there is a record from DB users

```
id = 1
name = John
type = 1
```

If type = 1 I would like to init some other class, i.g. Admin

And folders structure will be

Models
  - User.php
  - UserTypes
     - Admin.php

How it's possible to realize this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using for polymorphic relation. Let's say a user can be extended by two models "Admin" and "Marketer", they will look something like that:

```
 class Admin extends Model
 {
      public function user() {
           return $this->morphOne('App\User', 'extendable');
      }
 }
```

And the User model:

```
 class User extends Model
 {
      public function extendable() {
           return $this->morphTo();
      }
 }
```

Of course you will also need to add two columns to your User model `extendable_id` and `extendable_type` to hold the relation.

To read more you can check laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Comment: thanks. But how it's possible by, i.g. $user = User::findOrFail($id);
after based on TYPE value continue to work with $user as Admin or Marketer?

Comment: `$user->extendable` will be the Admin or Marketer model.

Comment: Am I right that for get "admin" user I need to call directly Admin class ?

Comment: because I don't see any information about extendable_type on https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Comment: I've adapted their example - they choose to show polymorphic relations on comments - so their columns are `commentable_type` and `commentable_id` -> for your case I tought 'extendable' is more suited, but you can change it to whatever you want.

Comment: If you want to get directly the Admin class then yes, you can find the Admin model (ex:`$admin = Admin::findOrFail(1);` and then get the user by using the relation like that `$user = $admin->user`.